# what is the use of tpc.googlesyndication.com/sodar/sodar2.js script in gpt.js?

Tags: javascript, adsense, google-ad-manager, google-publisher-tag

I am integrating Google Publisher Tags library in client side of webapp.
Google Publisher Tags library (gpt.js) triggers to load tpc.googlesyndication.com/sodar/sodar2.js script. What is the use of this sodar2.js script?